# Why do I get the error 'bash: ./install.sh: No such file or directory' when installing printer driver on openSUSE?

Tags: linux, installation, drivers, printer, opensuse

I am attempting to install a Canon MX340 driver on my machine which runs openSUSE 13.1.

When I tried to configure my printer, the driver was not found.

I went to the Canon website, found my printer and have been following the guide at (and, yes, I went in and changed my firewall settings as per the guide), and now after changing directories I type the command

```
./install.sh
```

and get the error

```
bash: ./install.sh: No such file or directory
```

I also received a similar error once before when attempting to install stockfish from source.  After typing

```
./configure
```

I got the error

```
bash: ./configure: no such file or directory
```

I recently installed openSUSE.
Is there something so obvious that I should have done that no one bothered to mention it?

UPDATE:

```
mike@linux-u32c:~/Downloads/cnijfilter-mx340series-3.30-1-i386-rpm> ./install.sh
==================================================

Canon Inkjet Printer Driver Ver.3.30-1 for Linux
Copyright CANON INC. 2001-2010
All Rights Reserved.

==================================================
Password: 
Command executed = rpm -Uvh ./packages/cnijfilter-common-3.30-1.i386.rpm
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
   1:cnijfilter-common-3.30-1         ################################# [100%]
Command executed = rpm -Uvh ./packages/cnijfilter-mx340series-3.30-1.i386.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libpangox-1.0.so.0 is needed by cnijfilter-mx340series-3.30-1.i386
        libpng12.so.0 is needed by cnijfilter-mx340series-3.30-1.i386
        libtiff.so.3 is needed by cnijfilter-mx340series-3.30-1.i386
        libxml2 is needed by cnijfilter-mx340series-3.30-1.i386
Command executed = rpm -e cnijfilter-common
mike@linux-u32c:~/Downloads/cnijfilter-mx340series-3.30-1-i386-rpm>
```

I don't know what I did wrong before, but now the `./install.sh` command seems to want to work; however, it seems there are some packages I have not installed.
Are there any suggestions which packages to install/information I should be able to extract from this error to help me resolve these dependency issues?

Comment: Are you trying to install 32-bit stuff on a 64-bit OS? I saw such errors in Lubuntu.

Comment: Is the file actually there? What is the output of `ls -l install.sh`?

Comment: did you change to the directory containing the sources?

Comment: Maybe you just forgot to uncompress/extract the sources with `tar xvzf *.tar.gz`

Comment: vasa1; this is a 32 bit version of openSUSE

Comment: sathya; yes, i did change to the proper directory

Comment: kwaio; i extracted the sources by right clicking and extracting to the current directory

Comment: user55325;                                                    mike@linux-u32c:~/Downloads/cnijfilter-mx340series-3.30-1-i386-rpm> ls
install.sh  packages  resources